# React: Different automatic states per map item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a form that allows the user to add more options using an add button. The catch is that each input has a helper text that shows the characters remaining (max is 200), the problem is that I couldn't think of a way to have a state that gets the length of the target input value in a automatic way. Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleOnChange(evt) {
    setValue(evt.target.value);
  }

  const inputList= [
    {
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
    },
  ];

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(inputList);

  function handleAddOptionInput() {
    const newList = inputs.map((option) => option);
    newList.push({
      id: ``});
      setInputs(newList);
  }


  return (
    <div className="container">
      {inputs.map((input) => (
        <div key={input.id}>
          <input
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            className="input"
            placeholder='Type something here'
            type="text"
          />
          <span className="helper-text">
            {maxLength - value.length} characters remaining
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleAddOptionInput} className="button">
        Add new input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The characters count is working, but if I write something in the first input, se helper text of the second one also gets changed.

Is there a way to make each input helper text get it's own input value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

You've only a single `value` state that is used/updated by all mapped inputs and length check.

## Solution

Convert your inputs to controlled inputs and store their values in the `inputs` state along with the `id`s.

1. Update `handleOnChange` to consume an id (for updating) and the `onChange` event.

   ```
   const handleOnChange = (id) => (evt) => {
     setInputs((inputs) =>
       inputs.map((input) =>
         input.id === id
           ? {
               ...input,
               value: evt.target.value
             }
           : input
       )
     );
   };
   ```
2. Update the mapping to pass the id to the `onChange` handler, use the `input.value` from state, and use the `input.value.length` for computing remaining characters.

   ```
   {inputs.map((input) => (
     <div key={input.id}>
       <input
         value={input.value}
         onChange={handleOnChange(input.id)}
         className="input"
         placeholder="Type something here"
         type="text"
       />
       <span className="helper-text">
         {maxLength - input.value.length} characters remaining
       </span>
     </div>
   ))}
   ```
3. Update `handleAddOptionInput` to add new inputs with proper `id` and new empty `value` state.

   ```
   function handleAddOptionInput() {
     setInputs((inputs) => [
       ...inputs,
       {
         id: /* function to generate unique ids */,
         value: ""
       }
     ]);
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-different-automatic-states-per-map-item]

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to handle all the input values using a single string type state variable. Instead create an object and assign the keys with updated values(like a dictionary, key value pair)

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  const maxLength = 100;
  function handleOnChange(evt, id) {
    console.log(id);
    var clone = { ...value };
    clone[id] = evt.target.value;
    setValue(clone);
  }
  console.log(value);
  const inputList = [
    {
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
    },
  ];

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(inputList);

  function handleAddOptionInput() {
    const newList = inputs.map((option) => option);
    newList.push({
      id: ``,
    });
    setInputs(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {inputs.map((input) => (
        <div key={input.id}>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, input.id)}
            className="input"
            placeholder="Type something here"
            type="text"
          />
          <span className="helper-text">
            {maxLength - (value[input.id]?.length ?? 0)} characters remaining
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleAddOptionInput} className="button">
        Add new input
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared state for inputs and values. You also need to use controlled components to control the entered symbols.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mendel-xz88i?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const initInputList = [
  { id: 1, value: "" },
  { id: 2, value: "" }
];
const maxLength = 100;

export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState(initInputList);

  const handleChangeInputValue = (id) => (e) => {
    setInputs(
      inputs.map((input) => {
        return input.id === id ? { ...input, value: e.target.value } : input;
      })
    );
  };

  const handleAddInput = () => {
    setInputs((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      { id: prev[prev.length - 1].id + 1, value: "" }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map((input, index) => (
        <div key={input.id}>
          <input
            onChange={handleChangeInputValue(input.id)}
            type="text"
            value={inputs[index].value}
          />
          <span>
            {maxLength - inputs[index].value.length} characters remaining
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleAddInput}>Add new input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```